# .NET Data Provider that can Insert 300,000 Records Really Fast?

Tags: .net, sql

I am making an application that is able to display log files and search throught them, in C#. I need data provider that can insert 300,000 records really fast. Does anybody have any sugestions? I am currently using Microsoft Compact server 3.5 and that is going really slow. I tryed sqlite but it performed slow because I could not do bulk insertions.

Comment: @dban10: I think ".NET Data Provider that can Insert 300,000 Records Really Fast?" is a much better title than yours.

Comment: Define really fast and really slow.

Comment: For those who argumented my answer that transaction would slow down, it's totally false. Having a Begin and a Commit for a bunch of Insert is a lot more faster than Committing one by one every query.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it is available in the Compact Server, but if you want fast upload into the database, performing a BULK INSERT is usually the way I go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have tried SQL Server Express 2008 and the BULK INSERT that Colin Mackay mentioned.  But that is definitely the way to go for large transactions.